# Move Up, Move Down Buttons for ListBoxes in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, button, visual-studio-2012, selected

I am trying to make a Move Up Button, and a Move Down Button, to move a selected item in a ListBox in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. I have seen other examples in WDF, jquery, winforms, and some other forms but I haven't seen examples from Microsoft Visual Studio yet.

I have tried something like this:

```
        listBox1.AddItem(listBox1.Text, listBox1.ListIndex - 1);
```

But Microsoft Visual Studio didn't have an "AddItem" property in their ListBoxes.

For more information, I have two listboxes that I want to make my Move up and down Buttons work with; the SelectedPlayersListBox, and the AvailablePlayersListBox. Will someone be kind enough to give me examples of a Move Up and Down button in Microsoft Visual Studio? Thank you.

Comment: are you using Winforms?

Comment: You are a bit confused. You couldn't find a method called `AddItem` in `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox` in the ".NET Framework", which is not analogous to "Visual Studio".

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796109/how-to-move-item-in-listbox-up-and-down

Comment: @AntonSemenov Not really Anton. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio. Yes, I have checked that question as well but that's not how Visual Studio works, so. Which is why I'm asking this quesiton for more help.

Comment: it's still not clear for me what technology you are using. do you developing visual studio addin or application software?

Comment: @AntonSemenov Hi Anton, Microsoft Visual Studio is a development software that helps people make applications.

Comment: oh, there is high grade of incomprehension among us... i get that you are creating an application with help of visual studio... The language you use is C#, but what is project type? Its possible that you are on winforms or on WPF. for each option possible two suboptions - you are using standard components (they ships with VS) and 3d party components. Which is yours?

Comment: Well Anton, you can run multi-processor builds for all project types using Microsoft Visual Studio but, I guess there are different properties for each project types, but they work similar ways. :) I couldn't remember which one AddItem was, and it turned out simppler than I thought. In Visual Studio we would use ".Items" and then ".Add"

Comment: @Cindy Again, you are talking about an IDE, and everyone else is talking about a framework.

Comment: @DanVerdolino Oh. :/ Maybe that was why the buttons didn't want to move for me. x.x

Comment: @Cindy How's that sarcasm working out for you? Answer your question yet?

Comment: @DanVerdolino No but I'm still trying to look for information on how to make my move buttons work. Thanks for checking on me. :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sarcasm-free answer. Enjoy

```
private void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MoveUp(ListBox1);
}

private void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MoveDown(ListBox1);
}

void MoveUp(ListBox myListBox)
{
    int selectedIndex = myListBox.SelectedIndex;
    if (selectedIndex > 0)
    {
        myListBox.Items.Insert(selectedIndex - 1, myListBox.Items[selectedIndex]);
        myListBox.Items.RemoveAt(selectedIndex + 1);
        myListBox.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex - 1;
    }
}

void MoveDown(ListBox myListBox)
{
    int selectedIndex = myListBox.SelectedIndex;
    if (selectedIndex < myListBox.Items.Count - 1 & selectedIndex != -1)
    {
        myListBox.Items.Insert(selectedIndex + 2, myListBox.Items[selectedIndex]);
        myListBox.Items.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
        myListBox.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex + 1;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `ListBox.Items.Add()`

For the move-up, something like this should work:

```
void MoveUp()
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedItem == null)
        return;

    var idx = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
    var elem = listBox1.SelectedItem;
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(idx);
    listBox1.Items.Insert(idx - 1, elem);
}
```

for move down, just change `idx - 1` to `idx + 1`

Comment: What about the ListIndex part?

Comment: @Nefarion I would also suggest resetting the SelectedIndex/Item after re-adding elem.

Comment: Thank you Nefarion. There are no errors but it doesn't Move item :C