# PowerShell Winforms MoveUp/MoveDown

Tags: winforms, powershell

Have only recently started getting into PowerShell forms and it's proving to be a minefield on support once I hit a wall. There's so much out there for c# but more often than not I struggle to convert it to PowerShell.

The code below is a snippet of a much larger script for Skype stuff (excuse the poor late out, no point adding irreverent code). What I'm struggling to do is create Move Up/Move Down buttons for when my CheckedListBox is populated.

The CheckedListBox is important since everyone within the list will be added to a Skype response group, and everyone checked will be designated an admin of the group. The Move Up/Move Down buttons will be used for priority purposes when this type of routing is selected.

```
#Function for creating an "open file" button
Function OpenFileDialog
    { [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.Windows.Forms" ) | Out-Null
      $OBJFORM        = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
      $OBJFORM.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt"
      $TXTIMPORT      = $OBJFORM.ShowDialog()

      IF ( $TXTIMPORT -eq "OK" )
         { Return $OBJFORM.FileName } }



# ///////////////

#Function for importing users
Function ImportUsers
    { $USERS    = gc $TAB2IMPORT
      $SIPUSERS = @()

      foreach ( $USER in $USERS )
              { $USERSIP = ( "sip:" + $_ )

                $SIPUSERS += $USERSIP

                IF ( $USERSIP -ne $NULL )
                   { [void]$TAB2LISTBOX.Items.Add( $USERSIP ) }

                IF ( $SIPUSERS.Count -ge 2 )
                   { $TAB2LISTL.Visible = $TRUE } } }



# ///////////////

# Adds .NET assemby's and turns on visual themes in standard PowerShell.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()



# ///////////////

# Creates the parent form and controls
$SDC                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$SDC.Location         = '270,175'
$SDC.Size             = '900,600'
$SDC.StartPosition    = "CenterScreen"
$SDC.BackColor        = "Lavender"
$SDC.Font             = "Calibri, 8.5"
$SDC.FormBorderStyle  = "Fixed3D"

$TABC                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
$TABC.Location        = '140,20'
$TABC.Size            = '720,520'
$TABC.SizeMode        = "Fixed"
$SDC.Controls.Add( $TABC )



# ///////////////

#Tab controls
$TAB2                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$TAB2.Location        = '20,40'
$TAB2.Size            = '100,100'
$TAB2.Text            = "Response Group"
$TAB2.Padding         = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Padding ( 3,3,3,3 )
$TAB2.AutoScroll      = $TRUE
$TABC.Controls.Add( $TAB2 )



# ///////////////

#Tab 2 ( Migrate users to Skype )
$TAB2HEADER           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$TAB2HEADER.Font      = New-Object System.Drawing.Font( "Calibri",11,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold ) 
$TAB2HEADER.Location  = '50,30'
$TAB2HEADER.Size      = '620,30'
$TAB2HEADER.Text      = "This tab will create a response group."
$TAB2.Controls.Add( $TAB2HEADER )




# ///////////////

#Tab 2 Add Users to Hunt Group
$TABAGENTSL           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$TABAGENTSL.Font      = New-Object System.Drawing.Font( "Calibri",8,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold )
$TABAGENTSL.Location  = '50,420'
$TABAGENTSL.Size      = '200,20'
$TABAGENTSL.Text      = "Who do you want adding to the group?"
$TAB2.Controls.Add( $TABAGENTSL )

#Tab 2 Open File Button
$TAB2IMPORT           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$TAB2IMPORT.Location  = '50,450'
$TAB2IMPORT.Size      = '80,20'
$TAB2IMPORT.Text      = "File Import"
$TAB2.Controls.Add( $TAB2IMPORT )
$TAB2IMPORT.Add_Click( { $TAB2IMPORT = OpenFileDialog ; ImportUsers } )



# ///////////////

#Tab 2 ListBox for Users
$TAB2LISTBOX          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
$TAB2LISTBOX.Location = '320,120'
$TAB2LISTBOX.Size     = '200,200'
$TAB2.Controls.Add( $TAB2LISTBOX )

#Tab 2 Listbox Help
$TAB2LISTL            = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$TAB2LISTL.Font       = New-Object System.Drawing.Font( "Calibri",8,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Italic ) 
$TAB2LISTL.Location   = '550,120'
$TAB2LISTL.Size       = '150,80'
$TAB2LISTL.Text       = "All names within the list will be added to the response group. `nThose checked will be designated response group admins"
$TAB2LISTL.Visible    = $FALSE
$TAB2.Controls.Add( $TAB2LISTL )

$TAB2LISTMU           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$TAB2LISTMU.Location  = '530,260'
$TAB2LISTMU.Text      = "&Move Up"
$TAB2.Controls.Add( $TAB2LISTMU )


$SDC.Add_Shown( { $SDC.Activate() } )


$SDC.ShowDialog()
```

I bought PowerShell Pro Tools for Visual Studio but hit the same stumbling blocks in that if I don't know what tool it is I need to begin with, I can't figure out from the options available on screen. As a result I've resided myself to ISE until I die!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Here's a C# example, which looks like it's just changing item indexes:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748949/move-up-move-down-buttons-for-listboxes-in-visual-studio

Which seems doable via Powershell if you access the same methods on your button objects

Comment: It's funny you should link to that threat as that's the same one I've been trying to decipher for a few days. I know it can be done, it's just figuring out the PowerShell commands from C#

Answer (score -2):

I found a link on how to do it.

https://www.akaplan.com/blog/2016/05/move-selected-item-up-or-down-in-powershell-listbox/

*edit

I 'cleaned' up the code for my own use as shown below:

```
#Function for Move Down
Function MoveDown {
  IF ( ( $TAB2LISTBOX.SelectedIndex -ne -1 ) -and ( $TAB2LISTBOX.SelectedIndex -lt $TAB2LISTBOX.Items.Count - 1 ) )
     { $TAB2LISTBOX.BeginUpdate()
       $SELECTITEM = $TAB2LISTBOX.SelectedIndex 
       $TAB2LISTBOX.Items.Insert( $SELECTITEM, $TAB2LISTBOX.Items.Item( $SELECTITEM +1 ) )
       $TAB2LISTBOX.Items.RemoveAt( $SELECTITEM +2 )
       $TAB2LISTBOX.SelectedIndex = ( $SELECTITEM +1 )
       $TAB2LISTBOX.EndUpdate() } }


#Function for Move Up
Function MoveUp {
  IF ( $TAB2LISTBOX.SelectedIndex -gt 0 )
     { $TAB2LISTBOX.BeginUpdate()
       $SELECTITEM = $TAB2LISTBOX.selectedIndex
       $TAB2LISTBOX.Items.Insert( $SELECTITEM -1, $TAB2LISTBOX.Items.Item( $SELECTITEM ) )
       $TAB2LISTBOX.SelectedIndex = ( $SELECTITEM -1 )
       $TAB2LISTBOX.Items.RemoveAt( $SELECTITEM +1 )
       $TAB2LISTBOX.EndUpdate() } }
```