# How do I make a messagebox appear when the last item in a listbox is moved down?

Tags: c#, listbox

When a user tries to move the last item down in a listbox, I need a messagebox to display that the item is already at the bottom. The app allows a user to enter more items to the list, so having the message display when a number is reached, like with the top, will not work, here is the code I currently have:

```
    private void MoveUpButton()
    {
        if (selectedPlayersListBox.SelectedItem == null || selectedPlayersListBox.SelectedIndex < 0)
            MessageBox.Show("A player under \"Selected Players\" must be selected");

        if (selectedPlayersListBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Player is already at the top of the list.");

        else
        {
            MoveItem(-1);
        }
    }

    private void MoveDownButton()
    {
        if (selectedPlayersListBox.SelectedItem == null || selectedPlayersListBox.SelectedIndex < 0)
            MessageBox.Show("A player under \"Selected Players\" must be selected");

        else
        {
            MoveItem(1);
        }
    }

    private void MoveItem(int direction)
    {
        int newIndex = selectedPlayersListBox.SelectedIndex + direction;

        if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= selectedPlayersListBox.Items.Count)
            return;

        object selected = selectedPlayersListBox.SelectedItem;

        selectedPlayersListBox.Items.Remove(selected);
        selectedPlayersListBox.Items.Insert(newIndex, selected);
        selectedPlayersListBox.SetSelected(newIndex, true);
    }
```

As I mentioned above, the MoveUpButton works fine, but the MoveDownButton is giving me trouble.

Thanks for any help you are able to offer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move item in listBox up and down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796109/how-to-move-item-in-listbox-up-and-down)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would look just like the MoveUpButton, except you'd check to see if the SelectedIndex is equal to Count - 1:

```
    private void MoveDownButton()
    {
        if (selectedPlayersListBox.SelectedItem == null || selectedPlayersListBox.SelectedIndex < 0)
            MessageBox.Show("A player under \"Selected Players\" must be selected");
        else if (selectedPlayersListBox.SelectedIndex == selectedPlayersListBox.Items.Count - 1)
            MessageBox.Show("Player is already at the bottom of the list.");
        else
        {
            MoveItem(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it. Don't know why I couldn't think of that, probably means I should take a break.

Answer (score 0):

Another way for moving up/down

public partial class Form1 : Form {

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    btnMoveUp.Enabled = false;
    btnMoveDown.Enabled = false;
}

private void lstPlayers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {          
    btnMoveUp.Enabled = (lstPlayers.SelectedIndex != 0);
    btnMoveDown.Enabled = (lstPlayers.SelectedIndex != lstPlayers.Items.Count - 1);
}

    private void btnMoveUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var index = lstPlayers.SelectedIndex;
        var item = lstPlayers.SelectedItem;
        lstPlayers.Items.Insert(index - 1, item);
        lstPlayers.Items.RemoveAt(index + 1);
        lstPlayers.SetSelected(index - 1, true);
    }

    private void btnMoveDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var index = lstPlayers.SelectedIndex;
        var item = lstPlayers.SelectedItem;
        lstPlayers.Items.Insert(index + 2, item);
        lstPlayers.Items.RemoveAt(index);
        lstPlayers.SetSelected(index + 1, true);
    }       
}
```